# An $8$ oared boat is to be manned by a crew chosen from $14$ men of which $4$ can only steer but can not row & the rest can row but cannot steer.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Full question: An $8$ oared boat is to be manned by a crew chosen from $14$ men of which $4$ can only steer but can not row & the rest can row but cannot steer. Of those who can row, $2$ can row on the bow side. In how many ways can the crew be arranged?

I think in this question we have to choose 1 person (out of 4) who can steer. No. of ways for that =$⁴C_1$

Now 8 seats are left 4 on the bow side & 4 on the non-bow side. We are given two specific person to always be on bow side.
No. of ways of arranging on non bow side = $⁸C_4$×$4!$

No. of ways ways of arranging on bow side= $⁴C_2$×$4!$

My answer=$⁴C_1$×$⁸C_4$×$⁴C_2$×$(4!)²$

But the answer in book is $⁴C_1$×$⁸C_4$×$⁶C_2$×$(4!)²$

Comment: Does the question say that $2$ can row on the bow side or that $2$ can *only* row on the bow side?

Comment: It says 2 can row on the bow side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question should be more clear. I think what the question means is that of the $10$ who can row, $2$ can row *only* on the bow side. Now it does not mean that those two have to be chosen to row but if they get chosen, they must be chosen to row on the bow side.

So as you correctly worked out, number of ways to choose the person to steer is $4 \choose 1$. We then choose $4$ out of $8$ rowers (taking out two who cannot row on non-bow side) for non-bow side, which is $8 \choose 4$.

Now we are left with $6$ rowers to choose from for bow side or choose which two to leave, which is $6 \choose 4$ or $6 \choose 2$.

Then we can arrange on bow side and non-bow side in $(4!)^2$ ways.

That leads to total arrangements of ${4 \choose 1} {8 \choose 4} {6 \choose 2} (4!)^2$